# How to denoise a noisy image in matlab using Tihkonov regularization?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to write a code for denoising a noisy image in Matlab using Tikhonov regularization. For this purpose, I have written the following code:

```
refimg = im2double(mat2gray((imread('image1.png'))))*255; % original image 

rng(0);
Noisyimg = refimg + randn(size(refimg))*20; % noisy image 

%%  Accelerated Gradient Method
    
x = cell(size(zeros(1,Nbiter))); 
x{1} = Noisyimg; x{2} = Noisyimg; 
y = zeros(size(refimg));

for iter = 3:Nbiter
      
    y = x{iter-1} + ((iter-2)/(iter+1))*(x{iter-1}-x{iter-2});
   [ux,uy] = grad(y,options);
   GradFy = mu.*(y-Noisyimg)-K.*div(ux,uy,options);
   
   xn = y - t*GradFy;
   x{iter} = min(max(xn,0),255);
      
end
```

in which K, mu, and t are positive parameters that must be assinged. I have implemented the code with many different values for these parameters but I can not get a denoised image. I receive an out put image which is still very noisy. For this reason, I guess there is something wrong with the code. I really appreciate it if you could please help me to find the problem with my code. In the following, I have inserted the image that I have tried to denoise and also the energy functional that I have tried to minimize and the algorithm that I have used. Here, f is the noisy image and u is the image to be reconstructed. Many thanks.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you share the image you are using, and the maths of your denoising problem? Its not clear to me what you are doing in the loop. Seem slike minimizing the gradient of the image using a gradient descend method, but we can't really help fix the code if we don't know what its supposed to be implementing

Comment: @Ander Biguri Thank you so much for your comment. I have added the picture and algorithm to my question.